# Streaming CSV Source with AKKA-HTTP

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to stream data from Mongodb using reactivemongo-akkastream 0.12.1 and return the result into a CSV stream in one of the routes (using Akka-http). 
I did implement that following the exemple here:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.0/scala/http/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html#simple-csv-streaming-example

and it looks working fine.

The only problem I am facing now is how to add the headers to the output CSV file. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the fact that that example isn't really a robust method of generating CSV (doesn't provide proper escaping) you'll need to rework it a bit to add headers. Here's what I would do:

1. make a `Flow` to convert a `Source[Tweet]` to a source of CSV rows, e.g. a `Source[List[String]]`
2. concatenate it to a source containing your headers as a single `List[String]`
3. adapt the marshaller to render a source of rows rather than tweets

Here's some example code:

```
case class Tweet(uid: String, txt: String)

def getTweets: Source[Tweet, NotUsed] = ???

val tweetToRow: Flow[Tweet, List[String], NotUsed] =
  Flow[Tweet].map { t =>
    List(
      t.uid,
      t.txt.replaceAll(",", "."))
  }

// provide a marshaller from a row (List[String]) to a ByteString
implicit val tweetAsCsv = Marshaller.strict[List[String], ByteString] { row =>
  Marshalling.WithFixedContentType(ContentTypes.`text/csv(UTF-8)`, () =>
    ByteString(row.mkString(","))
  )
}

// enable csv streaming
implicit val csvStreaming = EntityStreamingSupport.csv()

val route = path("tweets") {
  val headers = Source.single(List("uid", "text"))
  val tweets: Source[List[String], NotUsed] = getTweets.via(tweetToRow)
  complete(headers.concat(tweets))
}
```

Update: if your `getTweets` method returns a `Future` you can just map over its source value and prepend the headers that way, e.g:

```
val route = path("tweets") {
  val headers = Source.single(List("uid", "text"))
  val rows: Future[Source[List[String], NotUsed]] = getTweets
      .map(tweets => headers.concat(tweets.via(tweetToRow)))
  complete(rows)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mikesname!! last question, i have actually an akka actor which is returning the data as a source from mongodb this way: (MyView ? GetStuff()).mapTo[Source[MyObject, NotUsed]]  -  How would you redirect this to the tweetToRow method knowing that it's returning a Future.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks one more time for your help. Actually the via() function looks not correct that way... this is what I get when I build my project...    Error:(155, 87) type mismatch;
 found   : akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[MyObject,List[String],akka.NotUsed]
 required: akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.FlowShape[Product with java.io.Serializable,?],?]
  I double checked the via signature but not sure how to refactor my code to get it to work. I am still new to akka streams and scala so really appreciate ur help !

Comment: Sorry Mike, my bad...i figured out the issue. now it's working perfect. Thank you very much!!!  Last question: How would you give the exported csv file a specific name with a timestamp?